# Why does sdkmanager not found even after export the path

Tags: android-sdk

I wrote last line those exports:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

even running `sdkmanager` in CLI, return not found.

`echo $ANDROID_HOME` returns the PATH.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: IIRC sdkmanager is located in `tools/bin`. Try adding `bin` to the `PATH`, i.e., `export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools`

Comment: After add those line in ~/.bashrc, run `source ~/.bashrc` and reboot computer, its worked!

Comment: If you `source` bashrc, reboot isn't needed. Also, it seems you have resolved the issue. Consider posting an answer.